# Opening camera in half screen and webview in half screen on same view on ios

Tags: ios, webview, split, camera

My requirement is that i want to open a webview in upper half of iphone screen and  camera for video recording in lower half.Is it possible and if its is please describe how to achieve this.I have been struggling with this for past 3 days.Heres how i capture the video

```
#import "RecordVideoViewController.h"

@interface RecordVideoViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecordVideoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    x=1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)recordAndPlay:(id)sender {
    [self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}
-(BOOL)startCameraControllerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
                                 usingDelegate:(id )delegate {
    // 1 - Validations
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil)) {
        return NO;
 }
    // 2 - Get image picker
    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    // Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
    cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    //3 - Display image picker
    [controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.Heres the code

```
//  ViewController.m
//  AppleVideoCapture
//  Copyright (c) 2014 NetProphets. All rights reserved.

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    AVCaptureSession * session;
    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput * output;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //1. SetUp an AV session
    session= [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    if ([session canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium]) {
        session.sessionPreset= AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    }
    //Get the front facing camera as input device
    AVCaptureDevice * device= [self frontCamera ];

    //Setup the device capture input
    NSError * error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput * videoInput= [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error with video capture...%@",[error description]);
    }
    else{
        if ([session canAddInput:videoInput])
            [session addInput:videoInput];
        else
            NSLog(@"Error adding video input to session");

    }
    AVCaptureDevice * audioDevice= [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput * audioInput= [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error with audio input...%@",[error description]);
    }
    else{
        if ([session canAddInput:audioInput])
            [session addInput:audioInput];
        else
            NSLog(@"Error adding audio to session");
    }

    //Customize and add your customized video capturing layer to the view
    CALayer * viewLayer= [self.view layer];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer * previewLayer= [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:session];
    previewLayer.videoGravity=AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    previewLayer.frame= CGRectMake(0.0f,530.0f,320.0f,-250.0f);
    [viewLayer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    //Configure the movie output
    output= [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc]init];

    if ([session canAddOutput:output]) {
        [session addOutput:output];
    }
    [session startRunning];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)recordVideo:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Record video called");



    NSString * path= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",NSTemporaryDirectory(),@"output.mov"];
    NSURL * outputUrl= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSFileManager * myManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError * error;

    if ([myManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
               if ([myManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error]==NO) {
                   NSLog(@"File removal at temporary directory failed..%@",[error description]);
                    }
    }

    [output startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputUrl recordingDelegate:self];



    }
-(AVCaptureDevice *)frontCamera{
    NSArray * devices= [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice * device in devices) {
        if ([device position]==AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            return device;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Recording Finished");

    ALAssetsLibrary * library=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Error saving file to photos album");
             }
         }];
    }
}
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections{
    NSLog(@"Recording Started");
}
- (IBAction)stopRecording:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Stop Recording called");
    [output stopRecording];
}
@end
```